# Hostapd kills ethernet connection

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, hostapd

Dealing with the exact same issue like this guy:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159306

Interesting that how this never answered and/or the issue still exist in 2023 but can be specific to the USB wifi card...

```
country_code=BO
#driver=nl80211 # does not work

interface=wlan0
bridge=br0
ssid=MyLittLeAP
hw_mode=g
wmm_enabled=0
channel=7
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=mysecretpasswordeee
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

#ieee80211n=1
```

What happens is when hostapd is started it literally kills the ethernet connection (no more outgoing packets on it) and what's even more strange that if I comment out the bridge even then, as soon as the hostapd process is killed everything starts working again.

USB Wifi Card used:

**Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter**

Comment: You'll have to add details to help figuring it out. Please provide ([edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1823547/edit) the question), before it fails : `ip link` ; `ip -br addr` ; `ip route`; `ip rule` ; `/sbin/sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` (could be empty) ; `nft list ruleset` (as root. could be empty). Then after it failed, again `ip link` ; `ip -br addr` ; `ip route` and also `/sbin/bridge link` ; `ip neigh` .